# websocket library with easy upgrade path to .net4.5 websockets

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, websocket, .net-4.5

I'm looking to add WebSocket support to an existing comet server implementation, and I am wondering if there are any reliable/stable .Net4 WebSocket libraries which will offer relatively little pain when we upgrade to .Net4.5 (and leverage the included WebSocket API).

Would it be saner use .Net4.5 immediately? It seems stable for my purposes. Can I go live with 4.5beta?

Comment: Would it not be easy to write a facade over an existing library to duplicate the 4.5 API?

Comment: Sure... that being the case, the closer the APIs, the easier it is to write the scaffold. I'm wondering if any libraries exist that might already have considered this issue.

Comment: I've gone with http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/ whilst waiting for general release of Win 8.  Note that 4.5 framework alone is not sufficient in order to use websockets without additional libraries. Would be interested to hear what you ended up opting for here? Thanks!

Comment: ATM, we're sticking with our current COMET based solution. I've no desire to reimplement such a thing once WebSockets in .NET go live with 4.5. I'm a bit let down by the current limitation to use Win8 because HTTP.SYS sees broken HTTP in pre-Win8 versions. Hoping that a patch is issued for HTTP.SYS so Win2008 can also chat WebSockets "natively".